# AppCompat no projeto não funciona no Android API < 11

Tags: android

#### Situação

Tenho no meu projeto a `lib` AppCompact em formato `.jar`, porém não consigo instanciar nada da biblioteca:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nas propriedades do projeto tenho o *Java Build Path*, porém mesmo marcado não é possível usar nada. Fiz algumas pesquisas, porém só encontrei outras formas de importar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Configuração do Ambiente

- IDE: [Eclipse Mars 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ihg7.png)
- SDK Target: [Android 2.3.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c087I.png) - Api Level 10

Tem como usar a biblioteca desta forma utilizando o `.jar`? O que pode ser?